# How can I get the amount of bytes transfered and received on the windows platform?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I want to know the amount of data that transfered and received on the windows platform. Is there any APIs that supply this information? I can only find the bandwidth information from WMI, such as data sends per second.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the amount of data transmitted/received (among other things) for each network adapter in the machine with [`GetIfEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). To use it, you'll need to get a list of adapters with [`GetIfTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or one of its relatives, such as [`GetIfTable2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

You could use some performance counters:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70xadeyt.aspx
In order to access Performance counter in C# you could have a look here:
http://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/perfcounter.aspx